# acl9 trying to set it up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Anyone have experience with this plugin? I have it installed but I have no idea how to implement it. How do I define the different roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their readme is in fact really good.

I just set it up and these are the steps:

1. Create a model class called Role
2. Create a migration for the roles table (see readme http://github.com/be9/acl9)
3. Add acts_as_authorization_subject to your user model (assuming you have something like that already. Check out the authlogic plugin. There's an excellent railscast about authlogic (I think #160)
4. Create a roles_users association table (for the exact migration, again, check out the readme)
5. That's it. You done.

You can now assign roles to your user by current_user.has_role! :admin

You can check if a user has a certain role by calling e.g. current_user.has_role? :admin

There are lots of examples in the readme.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit of documentation on the README: http://github.com/be9/acl9 Which part don't you understand?

Comment: Look down the README under Role Model & Subject Model